# Async Http Request from component in Blazor

Tags: async-await, blazor, dotnet-httpclient, blazor-server-side

Im creating a list of components in Blazor, each one of these components need to request some data from a webpage. The list are created as follows on a .razor page:

```
@foreach(stringcomp in Complist){
   <myComponent />
}
```

around 100 components are created. On all of these components the following URL request is preformed (using this code):

```
        protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
        {
            if (firstRender)
            {
                await GetUrl("some url here");
            }
        }


        public async Task<string> GetUrl(string url)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
            request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "get data service");
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
            string res = null;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                res = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            return res;
        }
```

Doing this I'm running in to some problems where most of my calls to *SendAsync* never returns a value. I have come to understand that this is because of a lock-state but for the life of me can't figure out how to solve it. most similar answers suggest setting *.ConfigureAwait(false)* but this does not yeald a different result in my case.

So my question is: Hos can i request webbpages simultaneously in different components and be sure that they won't hang/lookup. As theres many requests that some times takes a long time (5-10 sec) to complete it's not an alternative to do them synchronously.

It might also be of importance to mention that me code and pages are separated, every .razor page are using @inherits to get its functions/logic

Comment: Is there a reason why you make a request per `<myComponent>` and not a single http request getting all data you need to display ?

Comment: in total there's over 500 requests, some are slow to get an answer from, if i need to wait for my data before i display it the waiting time can get very long. An alternative would be to do everything in the parent and pass the data to the childs as it is received, but why would this be needed? I can't see why my approach aren't working as doing separate requests in different components should work fine (even if my case are some what extreme)

Comment: A browser is generally limited to 5 parallels requests (2 on mobile) and Blazor is not yet really multithreaded, That could explains your issue

Answer (score 1):

Try to use IHttpClientFactory as follows:

```
[Inject] public IHttpClientFactory clientFactory { get; set;}
using System.IO;
```

Your GetUrl method:

```
 public async Task<string> GetUrl(string url)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
    request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "get data service");


    var client = clientFactory.CreateClient();

    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

    string res = null;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        res = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    return res;
}
```

### Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpClient();

    // More code here...
 }
```

Hope this works...

Comment: @inject IHttpClientFactory clientFactory is only for .razor pages but my code resign inside inside of a .cs. my .razor page inherits the .cs.

Comment: Add this property into your class behind: [Inject]  public IHttpClientFactory clientFactory { get; set;}

Comment: tried your code and unfortunately the problem still persists, some of the SendAsync calls never returns (probably dead lock)

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Why do you have to instantiate 100 component and store them in a list ?

Comment: each component represent a different webpage, every component are suppose to fetch information about its own page (this is why every component has its own requests) and display it. Problem is that only a few of the SendAsync calls do return, most of them get stuck and never return anything.NOTE: as the list items are created in a loop, all requests are sent away almost at the same time.

Comment: Are you creating the component in a list ? Or you actually render them all in a parent component at the same time ? What about using Task.Delay(4000) between each call.

Comment: they are created and rendered in a loop at the same time. adding a delay could possibly be a work around but is ultimately not what i'm looking for. When the components are done fetching the data they are suppose to run StateHasChanged() and thereby update themselves. this should achieve a effect of items in the view "popping in" when they have loaded. This do work for the calls that don't lockup.

Comment: "they are created and rendered in a loop at the same time" Rendered in a loop ? If anything, they should be rendered in a parent component. You should store a reference to components, not the components themselves.  Use the directive @ref for this purpose.

Comment: Probably didn't phrase that correctly, they are rendered in a parent component, but as every new item is it's own component (that's being re-used) they are created in a loop (as shown in the question)